# Cannot redirect to a newly created page in php

Tags: php, header, include

Hello I am trying to redirect to a php file that I created in an existing project using the header function but it is not working and I am getting 404 not found as a result.

Here is the line I wrote:

```
header('Location:payme.html');
```

When I do the same for the already existing pages it works for example profile.php like this: `header('Location:profile.html');`

profile.php and payme.php are in the same folder

When I use the include function it works: `include BASE.'view/payme.php';`

I think the problem is in the .htaccess file maybe there is rule blocking it.

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
    #Header set Content-Security-Policy "..."
</IfModule>


# -- DEFAULTS --
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage fr

Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks


# -- DENY ACCESS --
<FilesMatch "^(\.htaccess)$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(\.htpasswd)$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# -- ERROR REDIRECTIONS --
ErrorDocument 400 /error400.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html
ErrorDocument 405 /error405.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error500.html
ErrorDocument 501 /error501.html
ErrorDocument 502 /error502.html
ErrorDocument 503 /error503.html
ErrorDocument 504 /error504.html
ErrorDocument 505 /error505.html

RewriteEngine On



# -- ERROR PAGE ---
RewriteRule ^error([0-9]{3})\.html$ /error.php?code=$1 [L]

# -- FAKE ACCES DENYING ---
RewriteRule ^controller/(.+\.php)?$ /error404.html
#RewriteRule ^cron/(.+)?$ /error404.html
RewriteRule ^datas/(.+)?$ /error404.html
RewriteRule ^email/(.+)?$ /error404.html
RewriteRule ^external/(.+)\.php?$ /error404.html
RewriteRule ^external/php/(.+)$ /error404.html
RewriteRule ^model/(.+\.php)?$ /error404.html
RewriteRule ^params/(.+)?$ /error404.html
RewriteRule ^trustee/(.+\.php)?$ /error404.html
RewriteRule ^view/(.+\.php)?$ /error404.html


# -- SITE PAGES ---
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /index.php?htaccess_url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Any advice could help, thanks.

Comment: What is the path to payme.html from the page you're trying to redirect from? That is the path you have to use in the Location directive.

Comment: is it payme.php or payme.html?

Comment: The path is Base.'view/payme.php"

Comment: It is a php file in which there is html code

Comment: You have to specify the Location from the perspective of an external user.  Make sure this works first.  `http://yourdomain/view/payme.php`.  Or `http://yourdomain/???/payme.php`.  Replace ??? with the path for your payme.php.  Then specify your Location with exactly the same path.

Comment: I tried that but same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by adding the created page's name in the main controller file index.php.